# How to reuse a allocated pointer correctly, since error "double free or corruption (! prev)"

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

I wrote following code to do some queries in `sqlite3` iteratively, but the error `double free or corruption (! prev)` came up.

```
struct Arr{
 int length;
 int *arr_;
};

void getValues(sqlite3 conn, struct Arr arr1, struct Arr arr2, int *values){
    int i, j, k;
    int state, nrow, ncolumn;
    char **res;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    // to build query like "select * from table1 where value1 in (1,2,3...) and value2 = 100;"
    char *query = malloc(sizeof(char) * (arr1.length * 10 + 200);
    for(i=0l i<arr1.length; i++){
        strcpy(query, "select * from table1 where value1 in (");
        for(j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
            char buffer[sizeof(char) * (int)(ceil(log10(arr1.arr_[j]+1)))];
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", arr1.arr_[j]);
            strcat(query, buffer);
            if(j == arr1.length - 1){
                strcat(query, " ) and values2 = ");
                char buffer_[sizeof(char) * (int)(ceil(log10(arr2.arr_[i]+1)))];
                sprintf(buffer_, "%d", arr2.arr_[i]);
                strcat(query, buffer_);
                strcat(query, ";");
            }else
                strcat(query, " , ");
        }
        printf("query: %s\n", query);
        state = sqlite3_get_table(conn, query, &res, &nrow, &ncolumn, &err_msg);
        sprintf(query, '\0');
    }
    free(query)
}
```

It turned out, the queries can be printed correctly, but right after printing all queries, the error `double free or corruption (! prev)` has shown up, even if I comment `state = sqlite3_get_table(conn, query, &res, &nrow, &ncolumn, &err_msg);` there is still the same error.

I think,

1. `buffer`, and `buffer_` not need to be free, so there should be no problem
2. maybe `sprintf(query, '\0');` or 'query = '\0';`was not a good idea to set the query to NULL, but allocating`char *query`inside of`for`and`free(query)` is not necessary for the application, don't know if it did necessary for avoid allocating errors. Anyone know how to do that correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The line `strcat(query, buffer_);` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because `strcat` requires the second parameter to be a null-terminated char array, but the variable `buffer_` is of type `char` (it is not an array).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I revised them to `char buffer_ = buffer[(int)(ceil(log10(arr2.arr_[i]+1)))];` does it then just like a pre-assigned array `char buffer_[100]`? Anyway, I tried that but the error still exist, anything else worth to try?

Comment: With the line `char buffer_ = buffer[(int)(ceil(log10(arr2.arr_[i]+1)))];` you are allocating a single char and assigning it the value of one of the elements in the `buffer` array. This does not make sense. The function `strcat` requires both its parameters to be null-terminated char arrays, not single chars.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel ahhhh, you are right. I wrote it correctly in my code but that was wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It turns out, the memory assigned to `query` was not enough. `char *query = malloc(sizeof(char) * (arr1.length * 10 + 200);`, here the `arr1.length * 10`, means that assign 10 blocks for every element in `arr1.arr_`. But a `,` ( strcat(query, " , ");) is added , so it needs than `10+1` blocks for every number (in real life case, 15 more characters are added, instead 1 in the example I wrote here， so that caused big problem).

So not only check the way you allocate the variables, but also the length of allocated unit matters.